# How to move the messages from blob to eventhub in azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, azure-eventhub

We designed an eventhub trigger which reads the messages from event hub and inserts the messages into cosmos. During this process if any unhandled exceptions/throttling for cosmos we are moving these messages to blob.
Do we have any way we can move the messages back to event hub from blob through azure portal?. This helps azure admin to move the messages to eventhub in the production

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think there is a way to move the message back in the portal UI.

I would use a combination of approaches here. First I would use [autoscaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/provision-throughput-autoscale) of Cosmos DB to lower the risk of you being throttled and to keep you from overprovisioning and thus overspending on Cosmos DB. Secondly I would implement a [retry logic with exponential back-off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/conceptual-resilient-sdk-applications) in your trigger to further minimize the risk of throttling being a problem.

If you still get failed events, you might not have to push them to separate storage after all. [All events remain by default in Event Hubs for seven days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#what-is-the-maximum-retention-period-for-events-). You can just reread the entire thing if you want.

If that is not a good approach, I would push the failed messages to a queue (Storage queue or Service Bus Queue) and have an Azure Function on a timer trigger to process the queue and send the messages back to the Event Hub again. Then it would be fully automatic and admin does not have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have any way we can move the messages back to event hub from blob through azure portal?

One of the workarounds is to use logic apps where you can create a workflow from Azure blob storage to event hub. Here is a sample flow of my logic app.

[image]

[image]